# Error while adding line to file using sed command

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to add the following line to the beginning of file using sed command:

**node /^$server$/ inherits default {**

Command: `sed -i "1i node /^$server$/ inherits default {" "file.txt"`

When I run the command locally from the server it's working for me, but when I try to run it from bash script using this command:

```
sudo ssh serverName sed -i "1i node /^$server$/ inherits default {" "file.txt"
```

I got this error message:

```
"sed: -e expression #1, char 2: expected \ after a',c' or `i'"
```

I added \ after the 1i but this just adding the word "node" to the beginning of the file.

The first line of the file need to be for example:

**node /^serverName$/ inherits default {**

I guess that I need to use regex in my command but I don't know how to do it.

Please assist

Comment: @TomFenech Yeah, the symtoms suggest OS X.

Comment: I tried that but still just adding the word "node". any idea ?

Comment: I don't think so; if it were BSD sed, `-i` would take a parameter, and `1i foo` would not be interpreted as sed code. To me it looks like a shell quoting issue; probably the command passed to ssh arrives in the other shell in pieces, as though the sed code were not quoted at all. EDIT: Does it work with `ssh serverName "sed -i '1i node /^$server\$/ inherits default {' file.txt"`?